# Make a button ADD a number to a label

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4

I'm fairly new to coding with Objective-C/Xcode, so I'm just trying my luck with the easy stuff, making sure I get it before moving on to something harder.

What I am trying at the moment is to make a calculator. I've done one of those simple ones where there are two text boxes and an equals button, so I'm trying a number pad calculator now.

What I'm stuck on is how to ADD a number to a label (NEXT TO ALL THE OTHER NUMBERS, NOT ADDED) when the corresponding button is pressed. I can manage to add one number, but not both.

At the moment, I am only experienced with vb.net, so I'm used to

```
label.text = label.text & 1
```

I'm not sure how to do this is in Xcode.

Any help, code hints, links (or code chunks :P) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add the number to the label.  Instead, have another variable which is your running total which is a number and then update the label with the text version of the number.  A good habit to get into is separating your presentation (view) from your data (model).  In this trivial example, create a variable to hold your data and make the UI reflect that.  Don't use the label as your model.

As a simple code example, let's say I had an increment button and I wanted it to increment the value of the label.  The action for the button is the IBAction increment function.

Header:

```
@interface CrapletViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSInteger _total;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

- (IBAction)increment:(id)sender;
```

Implemenation:

```
- (IBAction)increment:(id)sender
{
    _total++;
    NSLog(@"total");
    [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"total: %d", _total]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
label.text = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:([label.text intValue] + 1)] stringValue];
```

Comment: I wouldn't use UI elements as data containers and rely on casting.  It's a better practice (read up on MVC) to separate your data/model from your presentation.  This binds them.  Instead have other data/models to hold your data and simply make the UI reflect that.  In this trivial example, it doesn't seem that bad but it's a bad habit to get into ...

Comment: It's not my habit. I just provided what he asked for.

Comment: I don't think I worded the question right. What I mean is press a button, and the number is added NEXT TO the current text, like a calculator. You press 1, 2 and 3 and the display shows 123. I think I worded the question wring. Any advice?

Comment: `label.text = [label.text stringByAppendingString:@"1"];`